# Preview Handlers (Office 2007, Vista & Win7) - issue w/ reisize

Tags: windows-7, handler, office-2007, preview

Greetings,

I'm working on a preview handler for Office 2007, Vista and Windows 7. I'm basing my code off the following 
[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163487.aspx#S5).

The "guts" are done as it was pretty straight forward. I've been testing in Windows 7 (64-bit) Explorer. One thing I've noticed is the preview handler appears to "lock" the Explorer window and doesn't allow it to resize.

My handler derives from `FileBasedPreviewHandler`, the Control from `FileBasedPreviewHandlerControl`. The #Load override simply does:

```
MyViewer viewer = new MyViewer();
viewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
viewer.SetFile( file.FullName );
Controls.Add( viewer );
```

A couple things I've tried, a variety of times is to set, in the design view, the `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode` to `true` and `GrowAndShrink`

Now, the funny thing, i *swear* it worked once. Now, I can't get it to work at all.

If anyone has any input, that would be great. I think I posted all the relevant info, but if I missed something vital, let me know. I appreciate your attention to this question.

-Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, by setting the `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode` as state above, does work. Explorer is simply temperamental.  What I found was if you get strange behavior, you can use task manager to close the explorer process than relaunch it.

For the record, what I found works *99%* of the time is to to:

1. make sure all Explorer windows areclosed (w/ preview panel off)
2. unregasm/remove from ga
3. build
4. add to gac/regasm
5. run Explorer and check preview panel
6. rinse & repeat

I'm also using a throw-away win forms app to test changes that don't involve the integration.

Hope this helps someone looking.

-Cheers!